# Error with wix/Detox [err_package_path_not_exported]

Tags: android, react-native, detox

After running the commands to install wix/Detox appears the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something that helped me with this issue: to install detox 18.16.0

```
npm i -D detox@18.16.0
```